# Unable to connect node js to SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue while trying to connect to SQL Server. I am using SQLEXPRESS, nodeJs, mssql@3.3.0

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
server: 'LAPTOP-G1234567\\SQLEXPRESS',
database: 'AdventureWork2017',
user: 'sa',
password: '123456',
port: 1433,
options: {
  trustedConnection: true,
  useUTC: true
}
};

function loadData() {

var dbConn = new sql.Connection(config);

dbConn.connect().then(function () {

    var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);

    request.query("select * from HumanResources.Department").then(function (recordSet) {
        console.log(recordSet);
        dbConn.close();
    }).catch(function (err) {

        console.log(err);
        dbConn.close();
    });
}).catch(function (err) {

    console.log(err);
});
}

loadData();
```

I received Connection Error when I run the app.js file

```
name: 'ConnectionError',
message: 'Login failed for user \'sa\'.',
code: 'ELOGIN' }
```

I tried the latest version of mssql as well, but both versions get errors result, I can't find out the reasons why I can't connect to the server. 
I checked Services.msc, all required services are running,
I set the port to 1433 in the SQL Service Configuration Manager,
it would be great if you can tell me how I can connect the database via whatever methods/ verions.

Comment: The error is clear and has nothing to do with versions and connectivity. You can't have both `Trusted Connection` and a username/password. One is for Windows authentication, the other for SQL Server authentication. The `sa` account is *not* enabled by default. You *SHOULDN'T* use it, even for testing. With `Trusted Connection` only, your app will try to connect using the account it runs under, which is a *very* good idea. If you want to use SQL Server authentication, create a *different* account in SQL Server

Comment: I removed the `Trusted Connection` line but still have the same error. I tried the code when I am connecting the database server via Windows authentication and SQL Server authentication, but still have the same error. It is my very first time to connect nodeJs to the Database server, so maybe I miss some critical concepts here?

Comment: just in case someone has the same problem as me, I connected the database successfully by using msnodesqlv8. [The code is like that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8)                        
`const sql = require("msnodesqlv8");
 
const connectionString = "server=.;Database=Master;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}";
const query = "SELECT name FROM sys.databases";
 
sql.query(connectionString, query, (err, rows) => {
    console.log(rows);
});`